# Is there a way to compile class with the only profile and exclude it otherwise?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a maven project with the parent `pom`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>java8</id>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>java-7-early</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have a sub-module `project-mod-1`:

```
 parent
  |__project-mod-1
  |       |
  |       |__pom.xml
  |
  |__pom.xml
```

The thing is I want to add a class

```
public class J8SpecificUtil{
    //contains JDK8 specific utils
}
```

to `project-mod-1` but it will use `JDK-8` specific features. So I don't want it interfere with compilation for earlier JDK, but I do want it is added to `JDK8` builds and be used by user with JDK8 or later.

What is the common way to solve such a problem with maven?

Answer (score 1):

Just put a profile around you modules, default will be java7, with -Pjava8 you will get all the modules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>java7</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>java7</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>java8</id>
            <modules>
                <module>project-mod-1</module>
                <module>java7</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: But in case I have lots of modules is there a way to add one to compile to them in case `java8` is activated?

Comment: @SomeName the example I've given is at the top parent pom, so anything under the project-mod-1 parent would be excluded by default. So you could have many java 8 projects under project-mod-1 and they would all be controlled by the profile in the highest parent pom.

Comment: Never ever try this. better is to use toolchains and make a separate module for either jdk8 specific or jdk7 specific parts. Furthermore the IDE's won't handle that as well...

Comment: @khmarbaise agreed, I was answering the maven question without thinking of the implications. Thanks for the steer.